# How to find/rip out all dimension/measures on an SSAS cube (Extended Events)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssas, cube, extended-events

I am using Extended Events to analyse dimension/measure usage in an SSAS cube. I have used xmla template to create the event (from Chris Webb blog). I then have parsed the data into a staging table where I have stripped out the required field from the event data XML field.

```
select TraceFileName
     , TraceEvent
     , e.EventDataXML.value('(/event/data[@name="TextData"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as TextData
into #List
from
(
    select [file_name]              as TraceFileName
         , object_name              as TraceEvent
         , convert(xml, event_data) as EventDataXML
    from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('*path*', null, null, null)
) e;
```

I plan to then use `CHARINDEX` to find measures/dimension calls within the field `TextData`. However to do this I will need a list of all dimensions / measures in the SSAS cube. Is there a way to rip this out?

Comment: I have just found a site for this...https://bennyaustin.com/2011/03/01/ssas-dmv-queries-cube-metadata/